# Bootstrap navbar background color rules not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I try to change my navbar background color it becomes grayed out in `Google Chrome` inspector. Can't find a working solution on google.

It does change when I removing navbar-default but then I don't get the toggle icon on smaller screens.

I've also tried to apply the rules to navbar-default but same results. the background-color doesn't change.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New" ;
}  
.ttposter{
  color:black;
  height:400px;
  width:250px;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background-color:#e74c3c;
  color:#ffffff;
  border-radius:0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color:#fff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-nav > .active >    a:hover, .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  color:#eeeeee;
}
.headerImgText{
  color:white;
  margin: 10%;
}

body,html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--Custom css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
<!--Javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/movies.js"></script>
<title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body onload="loadFeaturedMovies()">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapsed" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Notflix</a>
        </div>

        <!-- LINKS -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="movies.html">MOVIES</a></li>
            <li><a href="users.html">USERS</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html">ACCOUNT</a></li>

          </ul>
          <!-- LOGIN -->
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="loginUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
              <input type="password" id="loginPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" onclick="login()" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `navbar-header` class. Under that you have a button with a **data-toggle="collapsed"**. Change it to **data-toggle="collapse"**

Plus apply css as indicated by Rahul:

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-image: none;
}
```

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26317/

Comment: Please mark the answer if it worked for you. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

try below code, u just need to remove background image

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-image: none;
}
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26314/) here

Comment: Thanks, it worked but now nothing happens when i click the toggle button

Comment: make sure you have jquery and bootstrap js file link in ur html page

Comment: @MeanSmoothie you can also refer this basic ex [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h) for your understanding